# Creating individual bash scripts from Linux History

Tags: bash, scripts, history

I want to be able to output my Linux bash history to a file. Then line by line create a new shell script with the content of the of each line.
I have tried this so far from the command line..

for example

The output of the history file

```
73  nmap -T4 -A -v 127.0.0.1
74  nmap -T4 -A -v 192.168.0.1/24
```

My first problem was the line numbers ... To remove them I applied this command.

```
history | cut -c 8- > one.txt
```

Which gave me an output like this ..

```
nmap -T4 -A -v 127.0.0.1
nmap -T4 -A -v 192.168.0.1/24
```

There is a problem here as the text contains spaces

```
cat one.txt | tr -cd '[:alnum:]\n\r~!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}\|;:<>,./?"`' | sed '/^$/d' > bar.txt
```

I used the above command to removed the illegal characters that Linux doesn't like to be included in a file name.

This is where I have hit the wall...

It's clunky and messy...

There has to a simpler way that is prettier...

Comment: Even though @vanadium s answer does not answer the question, by using  the `~/.bash_history` file and not the history command, you would circumvent all problems you described.

Comment: It solves one of the issues. Granted but as you said it not the answer in which I am looking for. Thank you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split the history file into files by line

```
split --verbose -l1 ~/.bash_history
```

(do this on a copy in a separate directory)

To add the shebang:

```
for file in *; do 
    sed  -i '1i #!/bin/sh' $file
done
```

Comment: That is brilliant thank you so much ..

Answer (score 1):

Do not bother trying to find out how to write your history out to a file. Your Ubuntu system already does by default to the file `~/.bash_history`. So it takes a simple

```
cat ~/.bash_history
```

to retrieve the contents of the file.

Comment: I am aware of that and maybe I didn't explain myself well.. 
What I wish to do is turn the history log - line by line into individual shell scripts ... 
For each command in the history log..

Comment: No indeed you didn't. There is a lot of explanation, first on just getting rid of the number. So in the end, you just want to split a text file into individual lines.